# How can I programmatically launch the toolkit datepicker on windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, datepicker

I have this peace of code:

```
<toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="SchedulerDatePicker"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Background="White"
                                    Foreground="Black"
                                    BorderThickness="0.5,1,0.5,0.5"
                                    BorderBrush="#77797A"
                                    FontSize="18"
                                    Value="">
                    </toolkit:DatePicker>

                    <Button Grid.Column="1"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            BorderBrush="Transparent"
                            Click="CalendarButton_Click">
                        <Image x:Name="ImageDatePicker"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           Margin="0,0,0,0"
                           Style="{StaticResource InfoEllipseImage}"
                           Source="../../Assets/Icons/datepicker.png">
                        </Image>
                    </Button>
```

All this code is inside a .xaml file in a project on Windows Mobile 8. I need to open the DatePicker 'SchedulerDatePicker' inside 'CalendarButton_Click' in code behind. How to do this? I really don't know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [point 6 here](http://transoceanic.blogspot.be/2011/08/wp7-create-datepicker-control.html).

This looks like what you need. Make a subclass of DatePicker as shown in point 6 of that blog post, use your subclass instead of the original DatePicker, and when you want to open it - call the ClickTemplateButton method. Oh, and don't forget to say thanks to the guy who wrote that blog post. :P

For some reason a method to open the picker was not added to the toolkit. You can take a look at its source code [somewhere here](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest).

Answer (score 2):

If you are programatically trying to show the DatePickerPage, you could also invoke the private method to do this in the toolkit. Something like this.

```
typeof(Microsoft.Phone.Controls.DateTimePickerBase).InvokeMember ("OpenPickerPage", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Type.DefaultBinder, this, null);
```

Comment: brilliant, reflection to the rescue